# Trying a function, but I keep getting an error

Tags: c, function, void

The goal is for the function to say hi ("Hello User"), but it keeps telling me that my sayHi function is invalid. I'm not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    
    sayHi();
    return 0;
}


void sayHi () 
{
    
  printf ("Hello User");

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always include complete and exact error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sayHi();

int main() {
  sayHi();
  return 0;
}


void sayHi() {
  printf ("Hello User");

}
```

or this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sayHi() {
  printf ("Hello User");

}

int main() {
  sayHi();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... or even better with `void` in parameter lists for `main` and `sayHi`

Comment: yup, however I skipped that as it would create more questions for OP at his current skills

Answer (score 2):

You need to either [forward declare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) the function, or put the definition before `main()`, so that the compiler knows about the function being called.